# Is this spider dangerous to humans?

Tags: bug-identification

Quito, Pichincha, Ecuador. I found this spider under a pile of toys in my home - my son's room. Seems to be a regular spider - found two or three of them in my office.

Its span is like 3 to 5 cm. I don't exactly remember.

What's this spider's specie? How worried should I be?

[image]

Comment: A photo that was in focus would help.

Comment: Any markings you noticed would be useful too. There are a few venomous spiders from the central American region

Comment: No special markings in that spider. Its opisthosoma was mostly light-brownish. My first thought was a latrodectus geometricus but the legs didn't look the same.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't many really useful markings on that unfortunately out of focus shot, but a couple of things stand out:  the rather bulbous abdomen and posture are consistent with a Theridiid (comb-footed) spider, and the last pair of legs appear to have a very suggestive light brownish color with dark leg joints.  This is one characteristic of Latrodectus spiders (Black Widows when young females, Brown widows at all stages of the females).

I would suggest that you have an adult female Brown Widow, Latrodectus geometricus, but it would really help to provide a better photograph to make a more certain identification.

This is not a terrible thing, since Brown Widows are generally regarded as relatively harmless among Widows - they don't appear to bite very much, and the venom appears to be far less troublesome than that of Black Widows.  They also apparently eat Black Widows with enthusiasm, for what that's worth.

Here's a general link to the spider, and a photo you can use to compare:
https://cisr.ucr.edu/invasive-species/brown-widow-spider
[image]